# Volume bounded by sphere and cylinder

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume

How do you calculate the volume of the sphere 
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$$
completely inside the cylinder
$$
 x^2+y^2=ax 
$$
Same question has been asked here [Volume bounded by sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ and cylinder $x^2+y^2=a|x|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414071/volume-bounded-by-sphere-x2y2z2-a2-and-cylinder-x2y2-ax?newreg=da36a48bc45f42ba903112e19490c71f#)
However I am not sure i agree with the answer on couple of points
1) The answer assumes that the figure is symmetric on all axes. However, the figure is only on the positive X-axis, so I believe the integral (if correct) has to be multiplied by 4 and not 8
2) Not sure about the limits in the triple integral especially the limits of R. The answer assumes it varies from 0 to a $ cos\theta $. However, I believe that R is sometimes "a" as well when it is going through the top part of the sphere.
Appreciate your help if i have missed something in the answer that is provided 
(Note unable to comment on the answered question, so posing a separate question)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming wlog $a>0$, for any $z$, $0\le z\le a$ the intersection area between the cylinder and the sphere is given by the [intersection area of two circles](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html) $S(z)$

- $x^2+y^2=a^2-z^2$
- $(x-\frac a 2)^2+y^2=\frac{a^2}4$

once we have found that area, the volume is given by

$$V=2\int_0^a A(z)dz$$